# Eligible for bounty in X hours glitch

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounty

I posted a question here ([Possible mistake in Lancaster’s QFT pg 351?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/786340/310742)) 2 days ago, but the site still thinks it was asked “yesterday”. I remember checking yesterday and it saying “bounty is eligible in 7 hours” and now it says “bounty is eligible in 11 hours”. Why did the time go up? How can the glitch be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

There is no glitch: The question was asked on 29.10.2023 at 22:10:40 UTC and questions become eligible for bounties exactly two days after they are posted, which is indeed in about 11 hours at the time you posted this question.

Unless you can reproduce the bug that it displays a shorter time like 7 hours under some conditions, there is no indication anything is wrong here.